# Получение аватарки пользователя VK Api

Tags: vkontakte-api, вконтакте, php-vksdk

Есть вопрос,данный код раньше работал стабильно,но после мая перестал(спасибо новому API) не могу понять,что тут можно минимально изменить,чтобы вновь получать аватар пользователя?
Имя и т.д по прежнему получаю свободно

```
<?php
require_once 'vkapi.class.php'; #путь к файлу vkapi.class.php
    $api_id = '6623689'; #id приложения
    $secret_key = 'CneQh5ceNy5dF8NdvGDA'; #секретный ключ приложения
        $viewer_id = $_GET['viewer_id']; 
// id пользователя,не знаю откуда брать будешь   
$VK = new vkapi($api_id, $secret_key); 
$respo = $VK->api('getProfiles', array('user_ids'=>$viewer_id,'fields'=>'photo,first_name,last_name,last_seen'));   
$id    = $respo['response'][0]['uid'];
$foto  = $respo['response'][0]['photo'];
$name  = $respo['response'][0]['first_name'];
$fam   = $respo['response'][0]['last_name'];
$last_seen   = $respo['response'][0]['last_seen'];
?>
```

Вот мой vkapi.class.php

```
<?php

/**
 * VKAPI class for vk.com social network
 *
 * @package server API methods
 * @link http://vk.com/developers.php
 * @autor Oleg Illarionov
 * @version 1.0
 */

class vkapi {
    var $api_secret;
    var $app_id;
    var $api_url;

    function vkapi($app_id, $api_secret, $api_url = 'api.vk.com/api.php') {
        $this->app_id = $app_id;
        $this->api_secret = $api_secret;
        if (!strstr($api_url, 'http://')) $api_url = 'http://'.$api_url;
        $this->api_url = $api_url;
    }

    function api($method,$params=false) {
        if (!$params) $params = array(); 
        $params['api_id'] = $this->app_id;
        $params['v'] = '3.0';
        $params['method'] = $method;
        $params['timestamp'] = time();
        $params['format'] = 'json';
        $params['random'] = rand(0,10000);
        ksort($params);
        $sig = '';
        foreach($params as $k=>$v) {
            $sig .= $k.'='.$v;
        }
        $sig .= $this->api_secret;
        $params['sig'] = md5($sig);
        $query = $this->api_url.'?'.$this->params($params);
        $res = file_get_contents($query);
        return json_decode($res, true);
    }

    function params($params) {
        $pice = array();
        foreach($params as $k=>$v) {
            $pice[] = $k.'='.urlencode($v);
        }
        return implode('&',$pice);
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: getProfiles уже лет шесть как устарел! И vkapi.class.php у вас жуть какой древний. Просто почитайте документацию и перепишите весь код под новый API 5.x (в частности под метод users.get)

Comment: ну может устарел,но работал же)Новый API увы не могу пока осилить,не понимаю)

Comment: @NasdomlanUrban3p, чья аватарка вам нужна? Именно своя? Именно через приложение?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если еще требуется, без vkapi.class
Если нужны свои данные, `user_ids` можно удалить

```
$request_params = [
    'user_ids' => $viewer_id,
    'fields' => 'photo,first_name,last_name,last_seen',
    'access_token' => $token,
    'v' => '5.80'
];

$respo = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://api.vk.com/method/getProfiles?' . http_build_query($request_params)));

$id = $respo->response[0]->id;
$foto = $respo->response[0]->photo;
$name = $respo->response[0]->first_name;
$fam = $respo->response[0]->last_name;
$last_seen_time = $respo->response[0]->last_seen->time;
$last_seen_plat = $respo->response[0]->last_seen->platform;
```